# MySQL compare emails and match even if one upper the other lowercase

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to compare MySQL strings and want to make sure they match even if the one entered is upper case and the one inside my database is lower case. How can I do this "comparison" inside an SQL statement?

Cheers,
-lony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE LOWER(col1)=LOWER(col2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change bot strings to `LOWER()` or `UPPER()` and then compare

Answer (score 0):

Don't do any `LOWER()` or `UPPER()`, just use case insensitive collation, which you probably already do. If you don't, I'd use `utf8_unicode_ci` - the ci in collation name stands for "case insensitive".

Comment: Good idea but the database was not set up by me and poorly  is case sensitive. :(

Comment: Well in that case, you could use [COLLATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html)